# Is writeObject() not necessary using the Serialization Proxy Pattern?

Tags: java, serialization

I am using the Serialization Proxy Pattern for a bunch of my classes and recently added FindBugs to my build process, and now I am wondering whether FindBugs is correct...

This is the class in question:

```
public class Block implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 584958030434385L;

    private final float confidence;
    private final Rectangle boundingBox;
    private final Rectangle baseline;
    private final BufferedImage binaryImage;
    private final List<Paragraph> paragraphs;

    private TessResult parentTessResult;

    private Block(final float confidence, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline, final BufferedImage binaryImage, final List<Paragraph> paragraphs) {
        this.confidence = confidence;
        this.boundingBox = Objects.requireNonNull(boundingBox, "boundingBox");
        this.baseline = Objects.requireNonNull(baseline, "baseline");
        this.binaryImage = binaryImage;
        this.paragraphs = Objects.requireNonNull(paragraphs, "paragraphs");
    }

    void setParentTessResult(final TessResult parentTessResult) {
        this.parentTessResult = Objects.requireNonNull(parentTessResult, "parentTessResult");
    }

    public float getConfidence() {
        return confidence;
    }

    public Rectangle getBoundingBox() {
        return boundingBox;
    }

    public Rectangle getBaseline() {
        return baseline;
    }

    public BufferedImage getBinaryImage() {
        return binaryImage;
    }

    public List<Paragraph> getParagraphs() {
        return paragraphs;
    }

    public TessResult getParentTessResult() {
        return parentTessResult;
    }

    public static class BlockBuilder {
        private final float confidence;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final BufferedImage binaryImage;
        private final List<Paragraph> paragraphs = new ArrayList<>();

        public BlockBuilder(final float confidence, final Rectangle boundingBox, final Rectangle baseline, final BufferedImage binaryImage) {
            this.confidence = confidence;
            this.boundingBox = boundingBox;
            this.baseline = baseline;
            this.binaryImage = binaryImage;
        }

        public BlockBuilder addParagraph(final Paragraph paragraph) {
            paragraphs.add(Objects.requireNonNull(paragraph, "paragraph"));
            return this;
        }

        public Block build() {
            return new Block(confidence, boundingBox, baseline, binaryImage, paragraphs);
        }
    }

    private Object writeReplace() throws IOException {
        return new SerializationProxy(this);
    }

    private void readObject(final ObjectInputStream stream) throws InvalidObjectException {
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Proxy required");
    }

    private static class SerializationProxy implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 12321313232553L;

        private final float confidence;
        private final Rectangle boundingBox;
        private final Rectangle baseline;
        private final byte[] binaryImageBytes;
        private final List<Paragraph> paragraphs;

        private SerializationProxy(final Block block) throws IOException {
            this.confidence = block.confidence;
            this.boundingBox = block.boundingBox;
            this.baseline = block.baseline;
            this.binaryImageBytes = bufferedImageToBytes(block.binaryImage);
            this.paragraphs = block.paragraphs;
        }

        private Object readResolve() throws IOException {
            BufferedImage binaryImage = bytesToBufferedImage(binaryImageBytes);
            Block block = new Block(confidence, boundingBox, baseline, binaryImage, paragraphs);
            for (Paragraph paragraph : paragraphs) {
                paragraph.setParentBlock(block);
            }
            return block;
        }
    }
}
```

The key point to observe is that it stores a `BufferedImage`, but internally it stores the `BufferedImage` as a `byte[]` for Serialization.

Now I get this warning from FindBugs:

> Class com.yob.dpc2.ocr.utils.data.Block defines non-transient non-serializable instance field binaryImage ["com.yob.dpc2.ocr.utils.data.Block"] At Block.java:[lines 18-95]

So I dived into the issue a bit and I see that I am not providing a `private void writeObject(ObjectOutputStream oos) throws IOException`...

So my question is: Should I provide that `writeObject()` method? If so, is there a way I can reuse either the `writeReplace()` method or do something else to prevent logic duplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I provide that writeObject() method?

No, because it can never be called, because of your `writeReplace()` method.

You're up against a limitation in FindBugs. Make your class an exceptional case.